# Multiplying two lists in python?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to print a chess-board like list and I'm hoping it'll look something like this :)

`row=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8`
`column = a,b,c,d,e,f,g`

```
board=[[1A], [1B], [1C], ......etc.]
```

Is there any way to do this? I'm still a newbie with python.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
row = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
column = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
board = [[str(i)+j.upper() for j in column] for i in row]
>>> print board
['1A', '1B', '1C', '1D', '1E', '1F', '1G', '1H']
['2A', '2B', '2C', '2D', '2E', '2F', '2G', '2H']
...
['8A', '8B', '8C', '8D', '8E', '8F', '8G', '8H']
```

#### What is happening

The code above uses double list-comprehension to create eight lists of eight elements each thus creating a product of the rows and columns and giving a 2-D board.

#### Simpler visualization

```
>>> a = ['a','b','c']
>>> b = ['a','b','c']

>>> print [[i+j for j in a] for i in b]

[['aa','ab','ac'],
 ['ba','bb','bc'],
 ['ca','cb','cc']]
```

Comment: In the cell value, yes, but you are numbering the columns by row and the rows by column.

Answer (score 3):

The most pythonic way in my opinion is to use the itertools standard library like so:

```
from itertools import product
board = list(product(rows, columns))
```

this will give you a list of tuples that you then can join in the way the above posters suggest (you might actually want to keep them as tuples, make a dict out of it for further usage for example instead of having a strings you could use

```
result = [{'row': r, 'column': c} for r, c in product(rows, columns)]
```

or, if you need to do something on the fly you just do

```
for row, column in product(rows, columns):
    # do something for each row colum combination
```

it is superior to a nested list comprehension in clarity, and it is a generator, so it's more memory efficient. The latter argument doesn't really matter in your case of a chessboard though.

Comment: This produces one list of chessboard positions; not a nested structure.

Comment: @MartijnPieters To be fair, the OP didn't specify a nested structure.

Comment: @AlexThornton: True, it is a little unclear what the OP wants here; but when you want to *print a chess-board like list* I am thinking board-shaped, e.g. separated into rows and columns.

Comment: @MartinPieters: If he really wants to print a chessboard in the console, row by column, then this might not be the best way, but if he wants to do it like he formulated (having a list of strings) using the product function is just more intuitive for a beginner than the nested list comp, that can be hard to understand. It would be a pitty if it would get lost in such a thread that there is the wonderful itertools library. I've encountered to many unreadable nested comprehensions

Answer (score 2):

You most probably wanted a list of lists:

```
board = [['{}{}'.format(row, col) for col in columns] for row in rows]
```

This produces a *nested list of lists*:

```
>>> rows = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
>>> board = [['{}{}'.format(row, col) for col in columns] for row in rows]
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(board)
[['1a', '1b', '1c', '1d', '1e', '1f', '1g', '1h'],
 ['2a', '2b', '2c', '2d', '2e', '2f', '2g', '2h'],
 ['3a', '3b', '3c', '3d', '3e', '3f', '3g', '3h'],
 ['4a', '4b', '4c', '4d', '4e', '4f', '4g', '4h'],
 ['5a', '5b', '5c', '5d', '5e', '5f', '5g', '5h'],
 ['6a', '6b', '6c', '6d', '6e', '6f', '6g', '6h'],
 ['7a', '7b', '7c', '7d', '7e', '7f', '7g', '7h'],
 ['8a', '8b', '8c', '8d', '8e', '8f', '8g', '8h']]
```

and you can address an individual row with:

```
board[rownumber]
```

or a specific chess position with:

```
board[rownumber][columnnumber]
```

note that the column is a number *too*! You'd have to translate from column name (`'a'`, `'b'`, etc.) to column number here:

```
board[rownumber][ord(columnname) - 97]
```

would do that, as `ord('a')` (the ASCII position of the character `'a'`) is 97. Indexing is 0-based; chess position 1a translates to `board[0][0]`:

```
>>> board[0][0]
'1a'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map:

```
 map(lambda x:(map(lambda y:str(x)+y,column)),row)
```

Output:

```
[
['1a', '1b', ..],
['2a', '2b', ..],
etc.. 
]
```

Comment: In Python 3 `map()` produces a generator, and the nested maps here are not exactly elegant and readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import product
row = range(1.9)
column = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F','G', 'H']
board = [['{}{}'.format(*pos)] for pos in product(row,column)]
print board

[[1A], [1B], [1C], ......etc.]
```

**EDIT**:

So `product(row, colum)` creates a generator that will produce `(1,'A'), (1, 'B'), ...,(8, 'G'), (8, 'H')` one at a time. In other words it will create every combination of a entry in `row` with every entry in `column`.  `'{}{}'.format(*pos)` takes the contents of the 2-tuple and splats, using the `*`, it into the format function. Another way to write it would be

```
board = [['{}{}'.format(r,c)] for r,c in product(row,column)]
```

Comment: @Rico I've added some explanation